# Exclude symbol from regular expression PHP

Tags: php, regex, replace

I'm currently using the following to clean a string from symbols/unknown characters:

```
$title = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]/", " ", $title);
```

However, I don't want to remove '&' from the string

Can someone help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: You are not removing '&' from the string, I do not understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `^` at the start of a character class: `[^... ]` means that all chars in that class should be excluded from matching. In your case this chars shouldn't be removed. So add `&` to the class like this:

```
$title = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9-&;]/", " ", $title);
```

Comment: That's what i meant :D also is it currently not removing dashes (-) too? I'm not sure if the dash after the 9 is required or it's there to  exclude it from being removed. Last question, by adding "&" to the list, would it also note remove "amp&;" ?   Thanks for your help!

Comment: The `-` is also excluded from removing and therefore part of the regex. If you want to remove `-` from the input string then remove it from the regex. If an `&amp;` in the input string, currently only the trailing `;` will be removed

Comment: so to not remove "&", "-" and "amp&;" it would be: $title = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9-&;]/", " ", $title);

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this nice cheat sheet, it'll come in handy farther down the road.

[image]